# What is the correct usage of the mixin classs for TCL language?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, tcl, mixins

Im attempting to update an old version of the *selenium-tcl* package to work with the new W3C WebDriver (or Selenium 4.0).

Original packages uses a few mixins for the webdriver class.

So I modeled what I saw and created a mixin file named **mixin_action_chains.tcl** [[1]](https://github.com/SavSanta/w3cselenium-tcl/blob/master/mixin_action_chains.tcl) which has a mixin class called **Mixin_Action_Chains**.

Whenever I attempt to use it I get the error:

```
% package require selenium
::selenium::Mixin_Action_Chains does not refer to an object
```

Im not sure why I've modeled it pretty much exactly as I have seen in the other files such as **mixin_for_scrolling.tcl** [[2]](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SavSanta/w3cselenium-tcl/master/mixin_for_scrolling.tcl)* file. What am I missing.

Here is the entire [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/SavSanta/w3cselenium-tcl)

Im not sure what else must be done for TclOO. Any thoughts.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Im not sure what else must be done for TclOO. Any thoughts.

### Update

[pkgIndex.tcl](https://github.com/mrcalvin/w3cselenium-tcl/blob/master/pkgIndex.tcl): The placement of the mixin-defining script [mixin_action_chains.tcl](https://github.com/SavSanta/w3cselenium-tcl/blob/master/mixin_action_chains.tcl) is wrong, it comes after the mixin has already been required in the previously sourced script [webdriver.tcl](https://github.com/SavSanta/w3cselenium-tcl/blob/f502ab5f8b39178154d11245d5ba5865bcfe281a/webdriver.tcl#L25), like entering directly:

```
% oo::class create C {
    mixin ::not::defined
}
::not::defined does not refer to an object
```

You need to change the order of `source` command calls in the `package ifneeded` script.

### For the records

Still, in the original version, there were unbalanced curly braces and brackets in your script, which broke sourcing of the file for me:

https://github.com/SavSanta/w3cselenium-tcl/pull/1

Comment: You might want to user a proper code editor that supports indentation and basic balance checks. `mixin_action_chains.tcl` is really hard to wrap one's mind around, the massive block of commented code is just another Pandora's box.

Comment: Sorry MrCalvin, I have to set this back to unanswered. Bit of a late update (currently my internet status is sporadic). So i merged the code yesterday but still recieve thr same error message. Further , and I forgot i did this but thr brackets werent the issue as i copy-paste into a terminal and the object creates. In fact deleting all procs still produces that error. Il have to so some further investigation and see what else it could be

Comment: You seem to have applied a [fix](https://github.com/SavSanta/w3cselenium-tcl/commit/f502ab5f8b39178154d11245d5ba5865bcfe281a#diff-da7d99bbba18ecf96210d455ac01b73eL29) already, but there is an explanation to it. See my update.

Comment: Yes I had figured it out. Though thanks for the explanation. I had to learn from a TCL from book that used 8.5 so alot of the OOP caveats and characteristics werent covered. Learning on the fly ;). Thanks again ive re-set it to solved due to your update block

Comment: Fine, but note, this is not about OO. Any command (proc, object) in Tcl must be defined before being used (this is not to say that there wouldn't be magic which can make such a definition lazy and just-in-time).